# WP Query for Multiple Post Types

Tags: wp-query, meta-query

I am trying to splice together 2 post types and pull in 8 posts/events greater than the current day. I am struggling to get the default post type posts to show up though. Right now only the events are showing up - and I think it is something to do with my meta_query. The code is below:

```
global $post;
$today = date( 'Ymd' );
$args = array(
   'post_type' => array('post', 'tribe_events'),
   'post_status' => 'publish',
   'posts_per_page' => 8,
   'meta_query' => array(
      'relation' => 'OR',
      'event_date' => array(
        'key' => '_EventStartDate',
        'compare'   => '>=',
        'value'     => $today,
      ),
      'date' => array(
        'key' => 'date',
        'compare'   => '>=',
        'value'     => $today,
      )
   ),
   'orderby' => array( 'event_date' => 'ASC', 'date' => 'ASC' ),
);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: what is `date`, is that a meta key your posts have?

Comment: @Milo Hi, no - I cannot figure out how to add the normal `post date` there. I am not even sure a normal post (default post type) has a key?

Comment: this just makes no sense.  when you show posts you want to show the most recently published but events need to show upcoming.  your not going to get any blog posts on your query because they don't have the meta keys that events have. you need to write custom sql or 2 queries, also the events calendar has it's own functions to show upcoming events.